# Setting UNNotificationSettings.lockScreenSetting programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I've been digging through [`UNNotificationSettings`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings) to see if there's a way to programmatically set (or request when you request for the notifications permission) either of these settings in System Preferences > Notifications > [App Name]:

- Show notifications on lock screen
- Show notification preview: when unlocked

The former defaults to true and the latter defaults to true and always. I'd either like to set the former to false or the latter to "when unlocked."

I fear there isn't an approved solution here, because the only instance method of `UNUserNotificationCenter` that deals with `UNNotificationSettings` is [`getNotificationSettings(completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649524-getnotificationsettings) and there is no way to provide defaults for these when requesting notification permissions.

Stock apps like messages have this set by default (it's unclear if they've requested this or if this is just the default config), so there must be some way (albeit, perhaps not a sanctioned one).

If this is the case, is there some way to AppleScript this or some `defaults`-fu that can achieve this?